# Get error "ksh.exe has crashed" when run the command in msys open with admin

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, jboss, ksh

When I open msys without admin option on windows server 2008/2012 and run "jbossctl status" command it gives me correct output.
But, when I run the same command in msys opened with admin option it gives me error "ksh.exe has crashed"
Can anyone suggest why it is causing and what should I do to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue on a WFM Application server that was using msys. In my case, even though the local account was an admin, there was an outside software restricting the account and what it can access. Looking further into the issue ksh.exe was trying to use the kernalbase.dll in system32 and that was totally locked down. Once I removed the software that was enforcing group policies msys went back to normal. In my case the software causing all the issue was Beyond Trust. I hope this helps anyone in the future that runs into this.